# How to have a hidable paragraph in an HTML email template

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm creating email template with variables in it. The variables will be replaced at run-time with one of two different sets of values as show below. The first set has an extra paragraph in the middle with a link embedded in it. The problem I'm having is getting the second and third paragraphs to have the correct spacing when they are combined. Is there some way to create a bottom margin from p3 to create that space between the second and third paragraphs?

Here is the template I am using. 
**Template**

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.body-div{
    width: 560px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.below-spacing, .p3{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.above-spacing{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.p1:empty, .p2:empty, .p3:empty{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="body-div">
        <div class="below-spacing above-spacing">{{FirstParagraph}}</div>
        <div><span class= "p1">{{MidParagraphPart1}}</span><a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="p2">{{MidParagraphPart2}}</span></a><span class="p3">{{MidParagraphPart3}}</span></div>
        <div>{{LastParagraph}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Template]

**Example 1**
In this example I've inserted values into all the variables showing all three paragraphs and the link with text in it. Notice how paragraphs two and three do not space correctly in a browser. The CSS is the same as above.

```
</style>
<body>
    <div class="body-div">
        <div class="below-spacing above-spacing">Section of text #1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor porta wisi, sed et dui lacinia facilisi tincidunt hendrerit, risus sodales ipsum semper nulla sit, sed cursus sapiente, aliquam tincidunt sed leo arcu in.</div>
        <div><span class= "p1">Section of Text #2, Part #1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span><a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="p2">(Part #2) Link text</span></a><span class="p3"> Part #3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et eget.</span></div>
        <div>Section of text #3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amett, at consectetuer id sollicitudin amet posuere. </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example 1]

**Example 2**
In this example I've replaced only the first and last variables with text. The middle paragraph is hidden and both paragraphs are spaced correctly. The CSS is the same as above.

```
</style>
<body>
    <div class="body-div">
        <div class="below-spacing above-spacing">Section of text #1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolor porta wisi, sed et dui lacinia facilisi tincidunt hendrerit, risus sodales ipsum semper nulla sit, sed cursus sapiente, aliquam tincidunt sed leo arcu in.</div>
        <div><span class= "p1"></span><a href="https://www.google.com"><span class="p2"></span></a><span class="p3"></span></div>
        <div>Section of text #3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amett, at consectetuer id sollicitudin amet posuere. </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example 2]

Comment: I didn't see any `<span class="p2"></span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add this to the end of your css.

   ```
   .hidden{
       display: none;
   }
   ```
2. Then add the injectable variable Hidden to any element you want to hide on demand.

   ```
   <div class="below-spacing {{Hidden}}"><span>{{Paragraph2}}</span><a href="https://www.google.com"><span>{{Paragraph3}}</span></a><span>{{Paragraph4}}</span></div>
   ```
3. Inject "hidden" (no double quotes) for the variable `{{Hidden}}`. That will hide the paragraph with the correct spacing.
4. You can remove the `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` classes.

Answer (score 0):

The `span` is `inline` tag. We can not set margin for it. You should set `span` to `display: inline-block`.

```
.p1,
.p2,
.p3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

To hide second `span` you should add class empty for it:

```
<span class="p2 empty></span>
```

CSS:

```
.p1.empty,
.p2.empty,
.p3.empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I can't use 
<span class="p2 empty></span>. 
I'm injecting text into an html template to generate an email. I can only hide the paragraph by inserting or not inserting plain text into the three spans. This is why I'm using :empty to hide the three spans. 

display: inline-block; on the last span does work for displaying the margin below correctly. However, the paragraph doesn’t read like a paragraph. It only fits on the line above if there is space. I want the whole Section of Text #2 to read like one paragraph of flow.

Comment: span don't support :empty, your mean is if <span></span> has empty content, will hide it? You can use JS to check it and add class empty for it. Tell me if I wrong.

Comment: You are correct. It looks like the ".p1:empty, .p2:empty, .p3:empty" above is not doing anything. Spans with no text in them hide on their own so I don't need them. Email clients such as outlook will balk at trying to run JS so I can't use JS. If this was for a website it would be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some error in your HTML code.

1. your first span is missing " before the class name.
2. Your second span doesn't have a class. Maybe add p2 like you want.

I'm not sure to understand the whole question here, but why did you put a

```
display: none;
```

to your span?
Try

```
display: inline-block;
```

Another solution could be to remove span and add

```
<p>
```

instead and add that in your css

```
p{
   margin-bottom:20px; //can add a class p3 to your p.
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issues you noticed above. The display: none; was only supposed to be on the :empty cases which is now fixed. 

Like I said to WorkWe, the display:inline-block; doesn’t work because the text will not read like a paragraph. It only go on the previous line if it fits. The <p> solution has the same issue.